# Badge Based on Total Number of Questions Shared?

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request, sharing

I'd like to propose a badge for the "volume" of shares (*hopefully I'm not contributing to annoying dups*) ...

**Sharing Badge**

Currently the badges are based of the "volume" of vists to **particular questions** ... based on shares, but not on the number of *total* shares overall.

This has two major drawbacks as I see it ...

- Tags that have less overall traffic
  (while still being very valid) are
  unfairly misrepresented. The idea
  being a question/anwser might be
  really good +10 or more but the
  traffic (in general) is lower than a
  more "popular" topic.
- By only rewarding *super popular* questions there is no incentive to continually share links to questions ... which I belive would be encouraged by a badge rewarding such behavoir? Maybe something like: shared 10,100,500 ... whatever ... posts?

What are you meta-people's thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to have a minimum number of visits for those links (otherwise how would the system know that you'd posted one?).

Given that it doesn't seem that there's much to distinguish this from the [Announcer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/260/announcer) badge.